# Django: form as image

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a simple form in my template, index.html:

```
{% if stripped_thumbnail_file_list %}
        {% for thumbnail_name in stripped_thumbnail_file_list %}
        <div class="">
            <div class="">
                This is my form
                <form class="" action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="image" value="{{ thumbnail_name }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}thumbnails/{{ thumbnail_name }}.jpg">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>No videos are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

I want the index view to pull the {{ thumbnail_name }} value from this form and use it as a variable when the index view redirects to a different view that will use that name to play a matching video.

I have been unsuccessful in trying to pull that value from the form as I have it. I suspect this may because I'm not creating a Django form object. I tried to create that object, but I can't find any examples of a Django form object as an image like I have in my form.

What should that look like? Or, can someone make a recommendation on how to pull the value from the form as is?

EDIT: adding views.py snippet:

```
def index(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.POST:
        # get thumbnail_name from form
        # redirect to a new URL (hardcode thumbnail name for now):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('2017-02-01_04-29-10/video/')

    thumbnail_file_list = get_file_list(target_directory, ".jpg")

    stripped_thumbnail_file_list = strip_file_extension(thumbnail_file_list)

    template = loader.get_template('dash/index.html')
    context = {
        'stripped_thumbnail_file_list': stripped_thumbnail_file_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def video(request, file_name):
    print("this is the file name passed: " + file_name)

    template = loader.get_template('dash/video.html')
    context = {
        'file_name': file_name,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: How are you storing `thumbnail_name`?

Comment: thumbnail_name is stored in the thumbnail_file_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you need to declare the 'name' attribute on your form imput.

```
<input name="thumbnail_name" type="image" value="{{ thumbnail_name }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}thumbnails/{{ thumbnail_name }}.jpg">
```

Second: Why don't you just set the 'action' of the form to your 'video' function (when you perform a redirect, you are losing all your POST data).Then, from there you could retrieve the value: something like that

```
def video(request):
    file_name = request.POST.get('thumbnail_name')
    print("this is the file name passed: " + file_name)

    template = loader.get_template('dash/video.html')
    context = {
    'file_name': file_name,
    }
   return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of adding `name=` I didn't realize I was missing that. I changed my form action to `action="{{ thumbnail_name}}/video/"` and now I don't have to rely on the view(s) pulling anything from the form itself.